# SQL LEFT JOIN not working properly

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble getting the result out of my query.
I want to fetch the sum and total count of an unit sale in transactions, where the transaction is in a specific zip.

Here are my tables:

```
TABLE unit_type(
    id (Primary key)
    unit_name (varchar)
    department_id (Foreign key)
)

TABLE transaction(
    id (PK)
    commission_fix_out (int)
    transaction_end_week (int)
    property_id (FK)
    unit_type_id (FK)
    ...
)

TABLE property(
    id (PK)
    property_zip_id (FK)
    ...
 )
```

My **unit_types** table has the following records:

```
+-----+----------------------+----------------+
| id  | unit_name            | department_id  |
+-----+----------------------+----------------+
| 1   | WV construction      | 1              |
| 2   | WV resale            | 1              |
| 3   | WV rent              | 1              |
| 4   | BV industrial sale   | 2              |
| 5   | BV industrial rent   | 2              |
| ... | ...                  | ...            |
+-----+----------------------+----------------+
```

Here's how my query looks like:

```
SELECT SUM(commission_fix_out), COUNT(commission_fix_out), unit_name, ut.id
FROM unit_type as ut
LEFT JOIN transaction as t
ON ut.id = t.unit_type_id
RIGHT JOIN property as p
ON (p.id = t.property_id AND p.property_zip_id = 1459)
WHERE ut.department_id = 1
GROUP BY unit_name
ORDER BY ut.id
```

which results in:

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| SUM(...)   | COUNT(..)   | unit_name   | ut.id   |
+------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| 40014      | 11          | WV resale   | 2       |
| NULL       | 0           | WV rent     | 3       |
+------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
```

I was expecting another row with **WV construction**, but it doesn't show up. Anyone who knows where i am wrong with this one?

Comment: check this http://phpweby.com/tutorials/mysql/32, it may help with LEFT / RIGHT join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem. I'd like to share my result with you:

```
SELECT SUM(commission_fix_out), COUNT(commission_fix_out), unit_name
FROM unit_type ut
LEFT JOIN transaction t
ON (ut.id = t.unit_type_id AND t.property_id IN (SELECT id FROM property p WHERE
property_zip_id = 1459))   
WHERE department_id = 1
GROUP BY unit_name
ORDER BY ut.id
```

Instead of using an extra JOIN, i'd tried using a subquery in my ON-clause which gives my next results:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+------+
| SUM(..)   | COUNT()   | unit_name         | id   |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+------+
| NULL      | 0         | WV construction   | 1    |
| 40014     | 11        | WV resale         | 2    |
| NULL      | 0         | WV rent           | 3    |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+------+
```

I'd like to thank everyone helping me to fix this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the right join cause the problem.

try this :

```
SELECT SUM(commission_fix_out), COUNT(commission_fix_out), unit_name, ut.id
FROM unit_type as ut
LEFT JOIN transaction as t
ON ut.id = t.unit_type_id
WHERE ut.department_id = 1
GROUP BY unit_name
ORDER BY ut.id
```

what is the result ?

Comment: I guess it's not causing the problem. If i switch the right join by a (left) join, it gives me the same result.

Comment: Same as the other answer i commented, i get all the units. But, now it gives the results for al the transactions. While i only need the results from the given zip.

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve the problem, but why `RIGHT JOIN property`?

`LEFT JOIN property` instead would make more sense.

You see, `transaction` table is already `LEFT JOIN`ed to the `unit_type` which I assume is the base table of this query.

Answer (score 0):

That Right Join will effectively undo the point of the LEFT JOIN before it

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT    SUM(commission_fix_out), 
          COUNT(commission_fix_out), 
          unit_name, 
          ut.id
FROM      unit_type as ut
             LEFT JOIN `transaction` as t
                 ON ut.id = t.unit_type_id
             LEFT JOIN `property` p
                 ON p.id = t.property_id
WHERE     ut.department_id = 1 AND
          p.property_zip_id = 1459
GROUP BY  unit_name, p.property_zip_id -- added another column
ORDER BY  ut.id
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        (
            SELECT    SUM(commission_fix_out) total_fix_out, 
                      COUNT(commission_fix_out) count_fix_out, 
                      unit_name, 
                      ut.id
            FROM      unit_type as ut
                         LEFT JOIN `transaction` as t
                             ON ut.id = t.unit_type_id
                         LEFT JOIN `property` p
                             ON p.id = t.property_id
            WHERE     ut.department_id = 1 AND
                      p.property_zip_id = 1459
            GROUP BY  unit_name, p.property_zip_id -- added another column
            ORDER BY  ut.id
        ) tableA
        UNION
        (
            SELECT  0 as total_fix_out,
                    0 as count_fix_out,
                    unit_name,
                    id
            FROM    unit_type
            WHERE   id NOT IN
                    (
                        SELECT  DISTINCT xx.id
                        FROM    unit_type as xx
                                     LEFT JOIN `transaction` as t
                                         ON xx.id = t.unit_type_id
                                     LEFT JOIN `property` p
                                         ON p.id = t.property_id
                        WHERE     xx.department_id = 1 AND
                                  p.property_zip_id = 1459
                    )
        ) tableA
    ) tableC
```

Comment: Got a bit too fast accepting this answer, my apoligies.
Although i now get 3 units, it doesn't give me the result of per zip. The query now returns the sum of all the transactions. As you can see in following export:
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlEr3UxU5p5GdFZPWUJPQk5VelZXTnFweWJIQmEtZ0E)

Comment: I tried, it returned me the same result as in my original post

Comment: uhmm just a thought, why do you need to add this? `p.property_zip_id = 1459`? if `WV construction`'s property_zip_id is not `1459`, then it willnot show.

Comment: I need the zip_id, because i want to make a list with all the transactions from all the units (where department is 1) within that particular zip.
`WV construction` doesn't have a property_zip_id, that field is within the `transaction`table

Comment: thats why `WV construction` won't show because it has no `zip_id`. i try to update the answer.

Comment: But `WV rent`doesn't have a zip_id either and that record is fetched

Comment: I tried your query but i got a 1046 error, which i was'nt able to resolve.
I found an answer for my question, i posted the result.
Thx for your help and time!